# React - dangerouslySetInnerHTML <ul> and <ol> not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I want to display HTML as text

MY Code:

```
getDescription = () => {
    if (this.state.description) {
        return {
            __html: this.state.description.replace(/\r?\n/g, ''),
        };
    }
};

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {this.getDescription()} />
```

this.getDescription() returns : [image: Value]

```
__html: "<p> This is Testing</p><ul><li>Hello</li></ul><p>Testing</p><ul><li>First</li></ul><ol><li>Second</li><li>Third</li><li>Fourth</li></ol>"
```

my code output is :

[image: Output]

But I want to display like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: can you paste `this.getDescription()` data instead of image?

Comment: @CodeBug I have inserted the data.

Comment: Please check again. I checked it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-forked-3wb4h?file=/index.js